# Multipart email with swift

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Multipart messages are not being correctly shown on gmail when on the iPhone. I have:

```
$message->setBody($this->body, 'text/html');
$message->addPart($this->text_body, 'plain/text');
```

I have also used:

```
$message->addPart($this->body, 'text/html');
$message->addPart($this->text_body, 'plain/text');
```

But in both cases, when reading gmail from the iPhone I get the message as a 'MIME-attachment'... No html and the MIME-attachment cannot even be read. The message will display fine if I don't add the text part...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$message->setBody($your_plain_text_email_here);
$message->addPart($your_html_email_here, 'text/html');
```

I just had the exact same question and this worked for me on the Mac mail app, iPhone mail app and Horde (webmail, it came up as plain text.)

Answer (score 8):

I know this post is quite old, but in case someone finds this on Google like I did, the problem above is the mine-type definition. The correct mime-type is text/plain and not plain/text, like so :

```
$message->addPart($this->text_body, 'text/plain');
```

The final version that worked for me looks like this :

```
$message->setBody($this->body, 'multipart/alternative');
$message->addPart($this->body, 'text/html');
$message->addPart($this->text_body, 'text/plain');
```

Comment: you know `$this->body` and `$this->text_body` can be `array`, in this case we should set `$message->view` just before each `$message->addPart`

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and @Yuriy's one? Why should I prefer this? It seems to add the html body twice

Answer (score 1):

I would have to see the source code of the email to be able to provide you with a reason why you have problem.

```
$message->setBody($this->body, 'multipart/alternative');
$message->addPart($this->body, 'text/html');
$message->addPart($this->text_body, 'plain/text');
```

As far as I have see so far there is no email class out there that respects the RFC regulations.
I built my own and also built in a SMTP server into it so it sends the email directly not via mail().

Comment: would you change the content type in the html of the email? I have it as text/html... but I think it´s a problem of how gmail in the iphone interprets it, because it looks well from a computer, and also looks good on yahoo or hotmail in the iphone. Basically the problem is just reduced to gmail-iphone, so I´m leaning towards something with headers, content type, etc.